# How to get text from <p class=" "> tag using BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I am scraping some webpages and trying to get simple text from all

```
<p> </p>
```

tags. In one particular instance I am encountering a 'p' tag with a class:

```
<p class="SimpleBlock-module_p__Q3azD "> Some text here. </p>
```

Now using a simple:

```
Text = soup.findAll("p")
```

Results in:

```
Text = SimpleBlock-module_p__Q3azD  Some text here.
```

How do I only get the text part excluding the class name in Text above.

I want a general solution which should be applicable in all situations whether there is a class within the 'p' tags or not.

I am using Python3, requests, and BeautifulSoup4 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

p = """<p class="SimpleBlock-module_p__Q3azD "> Some text here. </p>"""
print(BeautifulSoup(p, "html.parser").find("p").getText(strip=True))
```

Output:

```
Some text here.
```

Answer (score 0):

In BeautifulSoup 4, `findAll` does not exist anymore (bs3) and is replaced by `find_all`

`find_all` gives a list so in your example you should access it with :

```
Text[0].string
```